# how to only add a top-level admin menu without it creating a sub-level-menu

Tags: wordpress, menu, admin, submenu, dashboard

Here is a the code snippet:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'travel_site' );

function travel_site(){
    add_menu_page( 'Travel Site Menu', 'Travel Site', 'manage_options', 'travel-site-menu', 'ts_admin_main_page' );
    add_submenu_page("travel-site-menu","View Travel Requests","View Travel Requests","manage_options","ts-view-travel-requests","ts_admin_vtr_page");
}

function ts_admin_main_page(){
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo    '<p>Testing main travel site menu page</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}

function ts_admin_vtr_page(){
    echo '<div class="wrap">';
    echo    '<p>Testing view travel requests</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

The problem is when adding the sub menu, the name of the top level menu("Travel Site") creates itself as a sub-level menu. See image:
[image]

Basically I don't want "Travel Site" sub-menu under the main menu "Travel Site", how do i remove the submenu "Travel Site"?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `remove_submenu_page('travel-site-menu','travel-site-menu');` after `add_submenu_page();`. Wordpress adds the menu-item by default, so you need to do these steps.